# How to check if enterkey is pressed in a TextBox in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net Text Box which accepts date in the format MM/DD/YYYY. After entering the date i will hit enter key.if enter key i need to execute server side code.How can we achieve this ?

The problem with Text box is it will fire the Text Changed event only if it looses the focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Panel.DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property to automatically click a button when the user presses Enter.

For example:

```
<asp:Panel Id="panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
  <asp:TextBox Id="txtDate" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button Id="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

If you don't want to show the button, you can set its `style="display: none"`.

Comment: This is the best solution IMO. Doesn't require you to write script and won't postback after every key press.

Answer (score 2):

you set jquery tag

so using jquery u can try something like this

```
$("#field").keydown(function(e){
     if(e.keyCode === 13)
     {
          // enter event
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the keydown event:

```
textBox.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "KeyDownHandler()");
```

Have `KeyDownHandler()` check the pressed key and if correct, submit the surrounding form or invoke an AJAX request. See keyboard codes at [Javascript Char Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.aspx).

---

Alternatively, textbox ID can be injected into jQuery from `.aspx` and assigned a direct keydown handler:

```
$('#<%=textBox.clientID%>').keydown(function (e) { /* Do server request; */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this Javascript function to check whether enter key has been pressed or not.

```
function checkEnterKeyPress(e)
{
     var key;     
     if(window.event)
          key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
     else
          key = e.which; //firefox     

     if (key == 13){
         alert(key);
     }
}
```