# What is the best way to set enterkey as default for a textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have gone through the question about [How to check if enterkey is pressed in a TextBox in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835453/how-to-check-if-enterkey-is-pressed-in-a-textbox-in-asp-net)

I have a search `textbox` in my masterpage and I want the enterkey to be set as default to do searching.

- Is it necessary to use [Panel.DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) if we not using `Javascript` or `jQuery`?
- What is the best way I can achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is.

if you are not working with js - then only from server side.

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnLogin.UniqueID;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how can I associate the buttonclick event when press enter

Comment: in the backend code its `Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnLogin.UniqueID;`

Comment: yes I did use that, but it dosen't picking up the buttonclick event when I press enter key

Comment: @huMptyduMpty the code is just  for " when enter is pressed" act as if i pressed btnLogin" nothing more.....