# Enter Key firing off an Response.Redirect on aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hoping someone can help. I am working on an aspx site, using the c# as the code behind. I have 3 input boxes, however when my cursor is in one of the input boxes, it seems to fire off the search_Click code which is fine if the cursor was in in the searchBox, but it seems to do it when the cursor is in the Username and Password Textbox. I dont have any javascript firing off this event, and what wanted to do was if user is in searchBox and hits enter, they fire the Search_Click otherwise if they are in either the username or password textbox and hit enter they fire off te code associated to login_Click. Hope that makes sense, anyone know why its firing the Response.Redirect even though I have no javascript/jquery teling it to.

```
//Front end aspx page
<input type="text" class="searchBox" autocomplete="off" id="searchBox" name="searchBox" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="searchBtn" class="searchBtn" runat="server" onclick="search_Click" />

<li>
  <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel"  AssociatedControlID="UserName" runat="server" Text="Username :" CssClass="usernamelabel" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="RegisterValidationGroup" CssClass="Username-Password" />                     
</li>
<li>
  <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel"  AssociatedControlID="Password" runat="server" Text="Password :" CssClass="usernamelabel" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" ValidationGroup="RegisterValidationGroup" TextMode="Password" CssClass="Username-Password" />
</li>
<li>
  <asp:Button ID="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" Text="Login" runat="server" onclick="Login_Click" />
</li>



//C# Code behind
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/SearchResults.aspx?q=" + Server.UrlPathEncode(searchBox.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, you can use the `DefaultButton` property of an `asp:Panel` object

For your login use something like... (untested)

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtUsername" />
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword" TextMode="Password"/>
  <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Login" />
</asp:Panel>
```

And then for your search have... (untested)

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSearch" />
  <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSearch" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The idea behind this is that if the focus is on a `asp:TextBox` within the `asp:Panel`, pressing enter will initiate the `DefaultButton`.  If you don't want a particular one to cause a post-back to the server, then update the `DefaultButton` so that it automatically cancels, such as...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSearch" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the text boxes that do not want the default form submit behaviour in a panel and set its DefaultButton property.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Panel, put your search textBox and button into this panel and set **DefaultButton="searchBtn"**. I refered to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836069/1380428